# Issue when adding response header from code

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application I have to add my own response header to send it to client. So am trying to add the response header using the below code. In case if I send Date as key it is throwing error even though I checked whether the header exists or not. Can any one suggest how to check before add to the headers in response.

```
foreach (var pair in Mydictionary)
{                        
    if (!response.Headers.Contains(pair.Key))
        response.Headers.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Use numeric DateTime value with custom formatting using alphanumeric characters for Key, if possible!

Answer (score 0):

ResponseHeaders is a NameValueCollection. You try to add a date as name. As a date contains invalid caracters for a name it doesn't accept as a name (key for you).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.headers?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_HttpRequest_Headers